# How can call a router from another current loaded route : Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I have loaded root route.

```html
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => { 
 // loading an HTML page
});
```

We have loaded an HTML page where we have a submit button, submitting on this submit button, we load the "search" route.

This "/search" route is loading successfully, but we have to load some dynamic content and after fetching all data, we have to load another route like "/searchoutput"

When we call :
`app.use('/searchoutput', router);`
or
`app.get('/searchoutput', router);`

But nothing happens without any error.

Thanks
Kumar Anil

Comment: You can use express router middleware.

Comment: Hi Gaurav,
I have tried the same, but not working. 
app.get("/searchoutput",router);
// app.use("/searchoutput",router);
Let me know if you have any live demo or clue.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understood correctly, you could do something like this,

If it is a POST request:

```
app.post("/search", (req, res) => {
 // some code

 res.redirect("searchoutput");

 });

app.get("/searchoutput" (req, res) => {
 // some code

 res.render("<your page>", { <yourResult>: <yourResult>);

 });
```

If it is a GET request:

```
app.get("/search", (req, res) => {
 // some code

 res.redirect("searchoutput");

 });

app.get("/searchoutput" (req, res) => {
 // some code

 res.render("<your page>", { <yourResult>: <yourResult>);

 });
```

If you don't want to reload the page, you could use AJAX, calling onclick a function that receives data from express.